# 3D Touch Shortcut Widget

Tags: xcode, widget, 3dtouch, ios10

i'm trying to implement new "quick menu widget" in iOS 10 available with 3dtouch.
My app has multiple today extension and apple guidelines report

> If your app has multiple widgets, pick one to appear in the quick action menu that appears when someone applies pressure to your app icon on the Home screen using 3D Touch.

I don't understand where i can "change" that!

With only one widget all works as well.

Comment: how to enable for the app which has a single widget in the app. BTW I am using dynamic short cut menu.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a new Info.plist key `UIApplicationShortcutWidget` which you need to set to the bundle identifier of your widget.

See the documentation at: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW32

Comment: I have only one Today widget in my app. Is there a way to prevent it from appearing when app shortcuts are launched or to detect that event?