# How to Enable Widget in Quick menu items in IOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, 3dtouch, ios10-today-widget

My app is using a single today widget. I want to get this on the quick menu items, like how apple is doing for notes, Photos etc.. and even third party apps like whatsapp also have it.

I hope it wont automatically enable it why because for all the third party apps which are having widget are not showing the widget on quick menu items.

I have tried this [iOS 10 quick menu widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241549/ios-10-quick-menu-widget) but no success.

BTW I am using xcode 7.3.1. And all the my quick menu items are dynamically created.

Please help me.

Comment: What *Quick Menu* are you referring to?

Comment: @DanielStorm menu appears on 3d touch of app icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using following thing's, it automatically show the widget on force touch or 3D touch:
1) deploy using xcode8
2) iPhone 6S or greater
3) if there is only one widget, then it will show by default but if its more than one, then you need define which one show in info.plist.

Hope this will fix your issue. Try restarting your phone if it doesn't show.

Comment: Any chance to find out from the widget if it's running as a Today extension or if it's invoked from the home screen via 3d touch?

Comment: Do you know how we could disable this? I have only one Today widget.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to "enable" anything. If your app has a today extension, it will *automatically* appear when the user makes the gesture for quick actions (3D force press on the app's icon). It doesn't matter whether you have quick action items or not!

But to get this behavior, you must compile against iOS 10 (so you will need to upgrade to Xcode 8). Otherwise, there is *no* way to get this behavior.